# boxes upper face pose estimation from pointcloud

Tags: python, outliers, semantic-segmentation, plane, open3d

I want to **estimate the pose of the upper surface of multiple boxes from the pointcloud**
[(link to pointclouds)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a1YXl4FQQVB-orsRlLDoaqCNEfDLP43x?usp=sharing)

I tried **Plane Segmentation**, and **Minimal Oriented Bounding Box**

But due to some outliers (that I didn't manage to remove by *statistical outliers removal*) I get the **pose rotated on the Z direction** as you can see in the photo below

can you please tell me how can I improve my pose estimation of the upper surface of the boxes? thanks.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from random import random
from copy import deepcopy
import open3d as o3d

# TODO: please change this directory
pcls_path = "/home/user/pcls"

origin = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(
    size=100, 
    origin=[0., 0., 0.]
)

boxe_pcls = [origin]
for idx, pcl_path in enumerate(os.listdir(pcls_path)):
    if pcl_path.lower().endswith('.ply'):
        print(pcl_path)
        box_pcl = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(os.path.join(pcls_path, pcl_path))
        original_box_pcl = deepcopy(box_pcl)
        original_box_pcl.paint_uniform_color([random(), random(), random()])
        plane_model, inliers = box_pcl.segment_plane(
            distance_threshold=0.05,
            ransac_n=5,
            num_iterations=100
        )

        inlier_cloud = box_pcl.select_by_index(inliers)
        #
        box_pcl.paint_uniform_color([random(), random(), random()])
        obox_ = inlier_cloud.get_minimal_oriented_bounding_box()
        new_obox = o3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox(obox_)
        new_obox.extent = [1.5 * obox_.extent[0], 1.5 * obox_.extent[1], 20]
        print(f"PointCloud {idx} has {len(inlier_cloud.points)} points")
        box_pcl = box_pcl.crop(new_obox)
        last_obbox = box_pcl.get_minimal_oriented_bounding_box()
        last_obbox.color = [random(), random(), random()]
        box_pose = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(
            size=100, 
            origin=last_obbox.center
        )
        rotation = deepcopy(last_obbox.R)
        # reverse rotation on Z axis
        if rotation[2, 2] > 0:
            rotation[:, 2] *= -1
        print(f"box {idx} has a rotation \n{rotation}")
        box_pose.rotate(rotation)
        # pcls.append(inlier_cloud)
        # boxe_pcls.append(box_pcl)
        boxe_pcls.append(original_box_pcl)
        boxe_pcls.append(last_obbox)
        boxe_pcls.append(box_pose)
    
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(boxe_pcls)
```

[image]

Comment: Collect multiple pointclouds of the same scene(if static) and run both spatial and temporal filtering to clean up the noise. Median Fitlering and Temporal filter to avoid too noisy data. You can also build your own bounding box estimator which fits itself under the assumption that there is some noise.